# Get results for sub query with matching values from a List

Tags: sql, entity-framework, linq

I have the following query:

```
List<int> genreIdsInt = genreIds.Split(',').Select(Int32.Parse).ToList();

resultsAfterGenreFilter = (from g in db.games
                   join gg in db.game_genres on g.id equals gg.game_id
                   where (gg.genre_id == genreId || genreId == 0)
                   select g).Distinct();
```

However, instead of getting the games with a specific genre, I wanted the games that are listed for all the genres that exists in the `genreIdsInt` array.

So if the game doesn't have genres that all of them corospund to the ones listed on the `genreIdsInt` list, they won't be included in the end results.

game_genres table

- id (int)
- game_id (int)
- genre_id (int)

games table

- id (int)
- name (string)

An example: If a game X belongs to genre 2. If the List contains 2 and 3, that game won't be returned, because it only belongs to genre 2. It has to belong to both genre 2 and 3 to return in the results.

I am creating the query in LINQ with Entity Framework. ASP.NET 4.6 / C#

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The typical approach would be to use [`All`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548541(v=vs.110).aspx) based predicate:

```
var result = db.games.Where(g => genreIdsInt.All(genreId => 
    db.game_genres.Any(gg => gg.game_i == g.id && gg.genre_id == genreId)));
```

Another way which IMO translates to better SQL is to count the matches:

```
var result = db.games.Where(g => db.game_genres.Count(gg => 
    gg.game_i == g.id && genreIdsInt.Contains(gg.genre_id)) == genreIdsInt.Count);
```

Comment: It worked, thanks. I want to just try to understand how it works in practice, but again, thanks for your help Ivan.

Answer (score 1):

```
List<int> genreIdsInt = genreIds.Split(',').Select(Int32.Parse).ToList();
genreIdsInt.Add(0);

resultsAfterGenreFilter = (from g in db.games
                           join gg in db.game_genres on g.id equals gg.game_id
                           where (genreIdsInt.Contains(gg.genre_id))
                           select g).Distinct();
```

Comment: It listed games that belong to either genres.  It should show games that are listed for all of those genres, not just a subset.